# How to enable / disable an input with a select VueJS

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Question originally [posted (in Spanish) on es.stackoverflow.com](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/276003/habilitar-deshabilitar-un-input-con-un-select) by [José](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/123821/jos%c3%a9):

> I have seen the example in JavaScript, and yes, it works and
> everything but as I can do it in **vue.js**, I've been trying for a
> while and it does not work. Sorry for the inconvenience.
>
> ```js
> <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
>
> <div id="app">
>   <p>{{ name }}</p>
>   <input type="text" v-model="name"/>
>   <button type="submit" :disabled="name == defaultName">Submit</button>
> </div>
>
> >
> ```
>
> **Javascript**
>
> ```
>     $(document).ready(function() {
>   $('#id_categoria').change(function(e) {
>     if ($(this).val() === "1") {
>       $('#d').prop("disabled", true);
>     } else {
>       $('#d').prop("disabled", false);
>     }
>   })
> });
> ```
>
> **HTML**
>
> ```
> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
> <div>
>   <select name='id_categoria' id='id_categoria' >
>     <option value="1" selected>Clientes</option>
>     <option value="2">Empresas</option>
>     <option value="3">Personas</option>
>   </select>
>   <input id="d" disabled="disabled" type="text" value="test">
> </div>
> ```

I know it's weird that I want to directly manipulate the DOM when you use Vue; I usually let the framework do that, This would be a possible solution

Of course, if it's a possibilty, you should take advantage of Vue's data-driven reactive nature, as tackling with the DOM is always tricky.

The solution would be to just create another variable and populate it on

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    name: 'Hello Vue.js!',
    defaultName: null
  },
  mounted() {
    this.defaultName = this.name;
  }
```

Comment: This is because you're trying to use jQuery methods instead of using Vue. The two don't mix very well (it's very rare that you want to be directly manipulating the DOM when using Vue; generally you let the framework do that.)  If you need help getting this sort of thing working within Vue you should include your Vue code in the question, not just the jQuery.

Comment: With Vue you won't use a `document.ready` function, you'll have a javascript object which is your _model_, and your select and input controls will be bound to elements in that model. See [Form Input Bindings](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html) for an overview. Your `<input>` will probably look something like `<input type="text" id="d" :disabled="categoria==1">`

Comment: Copied without attribution from [habilitar/deshabilitar un input con un select](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/276003)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is a vue template file using v-model instead of combining jQuery

```
<template>
    <div>
        <select v-model="id_categoria">
            <option value="1" :selected="id_categoria === 1">Clientes</option>
            <option value="2" :selected="id_categoria === 2">Empresas</option>
            <option value="3" :selected="id_categoria === 3">Personas</option>
        </select>
        <input id="d" :disabled="id_categoria === 1" type="text" value="test">
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            id_categoria: 1,
        };
    },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    options: [
      { content: 'Clientes', value: 1 },
      { content: 'Empresas', value: 2 },
      { content: 'Personas', value: 3 }
    ],
    inputDisabled: true
  },
  methods: {
    onChangeSelect(e) {      
      this.inputDisabled = (e.target.value == 1)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
   <select @change="onChangeSelect($event)">
    <option v-for="(option, index) in options" :key="index" :value="option.value">
      {{ option.content }}
    </option>
  </select>
  <input :disabled="inputDisabled" type="text" value="test">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    options: [
      { content: 'Clientes', value: 1 },
      { content: 'Empresas', value: 2 },
      { content: 'Personas', value: 3}
    ],
    selectedOption: '',
  },
  computed: {
    inputDisabled() {
      return this.selectedOption === 2;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <select v-model="selectedOption">
    <option v-for="(option, index) in options" :key="index" :value="option.value">{{ option.content }}</option>
  </select>
  
  <input :disabled="inputDisabled" type="text" v-model="selectedOption">
</div>
```